# Problem with a rolling ball in a rolling ring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, energy-conservation, rotation

Consider a ball with radius $r$ and mass $m$, which is free to roll inside a ring with radius $R$ and mass $M$ that is on a smooth plane. By dropping the internal ball from the initial position as in the figure below, the system is going to oscillate back and forth until equilibrium is reached. I am asked to determine what is the coordinate $x$ of the center of the ball at equilibrium.

I thought of balancing the dissipated energy (given by the potential energy $mgR$) and the work done by the static friction between the ball and the ring (that determines the torque providing the rotational acceleration around the center of mass of the ball), but I am not convinced at all by this idea, since I think that this would depend on the oscillations. Do you have any insight on this?

[image]

Comment: I think this is an interesting homework problem, but your question is about to be closed because it is asking about a specific problem rather than dealing with general concepts. You might want to reformulate your question so it doesn't get closed.

Comment: You talk about dissipated energy, but I don't see where any energy would be dissipated. Where is friction here?

Comment: @BioPhysicist the friction is between the inner ball and the outer ring. Since we pass from a state with non-zero energy (potential energy>0 and equilibrium) to one with zero energy (potential energy=0 and equilibrium), there must be dissipation. As mentioned in the accepted answer below, this friction is an internal force of the system ball+ring, and the proposed workaround works only in the absence of friction between the ring and the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Throughout the entire process, if we consider the system comprising both the ball and the ring, the external forces acting on the entire system would be the weight of the ball, the weight of the ring, and the normal force from the ground on the ring. Notice that none of these have any horizontal components. Thus, the horizontal position of the system's center of mass will not change.

Using this principle, let's first find the initial position of the center of mass, where the ball's center is at horizontal position $R-r$ while the ring's center is at zero:

$$
x_{CM} = \frac{m(R-r)}{M+m}
$$

When equilibrium is reached, the ball and the ring will be at rest, with the ball at the bottom of the ring. Letting $x$ be the horizontal position of the ball's center at equilibrium, since both the ball's center and the ring's center will be at position $x$:

$$
x_{CM} = \frac{m x + M x}{m+M}=x
$$

And since $x_{CM}$ will take on the same initial and final values, we simply have:

$$
x = \frac{m(R-r)}{M+m}
$$

Note that there's no need to consider the static friction between the ball and the ring even though it exists, because it would be considered an internal force when we treat the ring + ball as a combined system. Additionally, the question specifies the ground to be smooth, so there's no static friction between the ring and the ground. If there was, this method would not work! It would be very non-trivial.

Comment: "No horizontal components": what about static friction? I think this is a problem where the outer ring can start rolling. Also where is the energy going in your set up?

Comment: @octonion Static friction acts between the ball and the ring, but in the combined system we're looking at, it's an internal rather than external force, so there's no need to consider it. If you're talking about static friction between the ring and the ground, I would assume it isn't present, since the question stated the ground to be smooth. The question didn't explicitly state the source of energy loss, but I just reasonably assumed it to be dissipated in some internal force, e.g. rolling friction between ball and ring. Energy has to be dissipated for equilibrium to be reached.

Comment: I think the @chris97ong proposed a very nice trick here. Indeed the motion of the center of mass of any system of particles is governed by Newton’s second law for a system of particles, $F=M_{tot}a_{cm}$ where $F$ is the net force of all the external forces acting on the system, $M_{tot}$ is the total mass of the system, and $a_{cm}$ is the acceleration of the system’s center of mass. Since the $x$ component of the force vanishes, then the $x$ coordinate of the center of mass is constant!

Comment: @chris97ong, In case it wasn't clear I think you gave him the wrong answer. There is static friction between the outer ring and the table and this provides a horizontal force. You can use energy conservation plus the idea that the inner ball and outer ring need to end up moving at the same velocity to find the answer.

Comment: @WilliamTomblin, Well I guess you can always turn this in as the answer to your homework problem and see what grade you get

Comment: @octonion There is no static friction between the outer ring and the table, since it was specified to be smooth. What provides the horizontal force for the ring in the transient stage of its motion is the normal force from the ball. And energy is necessarily lost in the process because the system "oscillates back and forth until equilibrium is reached"!

Comment: Ok fair enough, I missed the "smooth" part of the problem. Maybe you are interpreting it correctly. I can't get rid of the downvote unless you edit your answer, if you care about that kind of thing.

Comment: @octonion edited! Thanks for bringing up that point nonetheless. Would be interesting to think about what this system would look like if it wasn't dissipative, or if there was static friction with the ground.